# Инициализация unique_ptr

Tags: c++, smart-pointer

Нужно объявить и инициализировать `unique_ptr`. Он должен указывать на структуру.

```
struct Node {
    int key;
};

unique_ptr<Node> head;
head = make_unique<Node>(new Node);
```

**Ошибка:**

> ```
> Node::Node(Node &&): невозможно преобразовать аргумент 1 из "_Ty" в "const Node &
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`make_unique` создает экземпляр `Node` передавая в конструктор свои аргументы. Смысл этой функции в том, чтобы не вызывать `new Node` вручную. Соответственно передавать `Node *` не следует. Далее, `head = make_unique` - это не инициализация, а присвоение. Инициализация выглядит вот так:

```
::std::unique_ptr<Node> head{new Node{}};
auto head{::std::make_unique<Node>()};
```

Comment: Второй вариант можно дополнить ещё и `=` вместо `{}`, оставаясь в рамках инициализации.

Comment: @VTT как присвоить что-либо uniqe_ptr после объявления? То есть в первой строчке объявление `unique_ptr<Node> head;` а в следующей (не в этой строчке) выделить в куче Node и присвоить uniqe_ptr. В вашем примере объявление и инициализация в одной строчке.

Comment: @zhukov Просто сделать присвоение на другой строке. `::std::unique_ptr<Node> head{}; head = ::std::make_unique<Node>();`. Инициализация при этом будет по-прежнему происходить на первой строке.

Comment: Стоит подчеркнуть, что в make_unique можно (и нужно) передавать параметры конструктора. К примеру `std::make_unique<std::ifstream>(path, std::ios_base::app);`